# Newline after \cases in \equation environment

Tags: equations

I have the following problem: I have an equation environment with three different lines. The first to should be connected with a 2 line bracket. The last line should be below the two. Just like if it were three independet lines of stuff. 
I use \cases to creat the bracket, but the last line will show up behind the two, not below. Tried multlines and eqnarray already.

```
\begin{equation}
 2 \text{x} 
\begin{cases} 
{}^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + e^+ + \nu \\
{}^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  
\end{cases} \\
 {}^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{3}\text{He}  \rightarrow \text{2} {}^\text{1}\text{H}
\label{eq:ppkette}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

The environment `equation` is made for one line equations, use `align` if you want to be able to break lines.
However, if you want one equation number for your three lines, the environment matrix can do the trick.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
 2 \times % Use \times rather than \text{x}
\begin{cases} \begin{matrix}{}^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + e^+ + \nu \\
{}^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma \end{matrix} \end{cases}
\\
{}^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{3}\text{He}  \rightarrow \text{2} {}^\text{1}\text{H}
\label{eq:ppkette}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

PS : there is a dedicated stakcExchange site for LaTeX related question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the alignment you're after, the following seems to suit your needs (aligned around `\rightarrow`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   2 \text{x} 
  \begin{cases} 
    {}^\text{1}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{2}\text{H} + e^+ + \nu \\
    {}^\text{2}\text{H} + {}^\text{1}\text{H} \rightarrow {}^\text{3}\text{He} + \gamma  
  \end{cases} \\
   {}^\text{3}\text{He} + {}^\text{3}\text{He}  \rightarrow \text{2} {}^\text{1}\text{H}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
   2 \times \Biggl\{\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    \ce{^1 H + ^1 H} \\
    \ce{^2 H + ^1 H} 
  \end{array} & \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    {} \rightarrow \ce{^2 H + e+ + \nu} \\
    {} \rightarrow \ce{^3 He + \gamma}
  \end{array} \\
   \ce{^3 He + ^3 He} & {} \rightarrow 2 \ce{^1 H}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Other alignments are also possible, of course.